# How to reference SSM parameter in another template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-parameter-store

If defining a SSM parameter in cloud formation one template like this

```
  KinesisStreamARNParameter:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "/${Environment}/Services/${Domain}/kinesis_stream_arn"
      Type: String
      Value: !GetAtt KinesisStream.Arn
```

How would I use in a different template file that defines a role? How would I refer to it under resources for the policy?

```
KinesisFirehoseRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: firehose.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: KinesisFirehosePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kinesis:*
                  - s3:*
                  - s3-object-lambda:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "${Bucket.Arn}/*"
```

Comment: have you thought to use the Parameter store in SSM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there are two choices:

1. [Export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) the arn of your `KinesisStreamARNParameter` in the outputs. Then use [ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) to reference it your second template.
2. Pass the arn as an input parameter to your second template. This will require you to manually provide the value when you deploy the second template, or create some automation wrapper that will populate that value for you before deployment.

Comment: It's failing with `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS with reason: No export named sandbox06-ODM-KinesisStreamArn found`. I can see the the export listed with that name in the CloudFormation console

Comment: @AntarrByrd Your question does not provide details how do you export and import the values. You can make new question with such details as this is rather new issue.

Comment: New Question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573472/cloud-formation-failing-to-find-export)

Comment: Would have been nice and simple if the export outputs could be sent to the SSM parameter store. That would allow cross-region parameter passing.