# Why do I get a "No Export Named" error when using nested stacks in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm defining an export in a CloudFormation template to be used in another.

I can see the export is being created in the AWS console however, the second stack fails to find it.

The error:

```
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS with reason: No export named sandbox06-ODM-KinesisStreamArn found
```

`template.yml`

```
Resources:
  KinesisStream:
    Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
    Properties:
      ShardCount: 1
      RetentionPeriodHours: 24
      Name: !Sub ${Environment}-${Application}
Outputs:
  Topic:
    Value: !Ref Topic
  KinesisStreamArn:
    Value: !GetAtt KinesisStream.Arn
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${Environment}-${Domain}-KinesisStreamArn
```

`firehose.yml`

```
KinesisFirehoseRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: firehose.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: KinesisFirehosePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kinesis:*
                  - s3:*
                  - s3-object-lambda:*
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "${Bucket.Arn}/*"
                  - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${Environment}-${Domain}-KinesisStreamArn"
```

`nested_template.yml`

```
  OperationalData:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        Domain: OperationalData
        Application: odm
        BucketPrefix: pie
        WhiteListCidr: !Ref WhiteListCidr
        VpcId:
          Fn::ImportValue: !Sub vpc-${Environment}-VPCID
        VpcCidr:
          Fn::ImportValue: !Sub vpc-${Environment}-VPCCIDR
        Subnets:
          Fn::ImportValue: !Sub vpc-${Environment}-PrivateSubnets
      Location: ./data/odm/template.yml
      Tags:
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        Domain: odm
        Application: !Ref Application
        Developer: !Ref Developer
        DevOpsAdmin: !Ref DevOpsAdmin
        Repository: !Ref Repository
        Team: !Ref Team

  DataEngineeringData:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        Domain: DataEngineeringData
        Application: data-engineering
      Location: ./data/data-engineering/template.yml
      Tags:
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        Domain: DataEngineeringData
        Application: data-engineering
        Developer: !Ref Developer
        DevOpsAdmin: !Ref DevOpsAdmin
        Repository: !Ref Repository
        Team: !Ref Team
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Is that everything in its entirety? Is this a nested stack by any chance Antarr?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary They are nested

Comment: Aha - that's the key bit, mind sharing the nested config? I can then let you know the solution :)

Comment: I added it above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the second stack fails to find it

This is because nested CloudFormation stacks are created in *parallel* by default.

This means that if one of your child stacks - e.g. the stack which contains `KinesisFirehoseRole` - is importing the output from another child stack - e.g. the stack which contains `KinesisStream` - then the stack creation will fail.

This is because as they're created in parallel, how does CloudFormation ensure that the export value has been exported by the time another child stack created is importing it?

**To fix this, use the [`DependsOn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute on the stack which contains `KinesisFirehoseRole`.**

This should point to the stack which contains `KinesisStream` as `KinesisFirehoseRole` has a dependency on it.

`DependsOn` makes this dependency explicit and will ensure correct stack creation order.

Something like this should work:

```yaml
Stack-Containing-Kinesis-Firehose-Role:
   Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
   DependsOn: Stack-Containing-Kinesis-Stream-Resource-Which-Outputs-KinesisStreamArn
   ...
```